# Create function that calculates a boolean return value for a given (floating point) time value based on edge transitions

Tags: c++

I want to create a function (in C++) that will return true or false for a given floating point time value.  The True or False return value needs to be determined based on a data set of True->False and False->True transition events that have occurred at specific times.

I could create an array of all of the transition events based on my dataset and then compare every single one of them with the given time value to find the most recent event that precedes the given time, but that seems horribly inefficient.  Is there a better way to do this?  Maybe some sort of binary search?  The other problem is that the dataset of transition events is continuously updated over time and I can't guarantee that the updates will be received in order (although they will have accurate timestamps associated with them).

Comment: If you want someone here to create a function for you, you've come to a wrong place. You have to try something yourself, and then if you have problems, ask specific questions here on SO.

Comment: The problem here is that you don't know enough about data structures. It all depends on the ratio of "seek" or "update" operations that you will have to service (and of course in practice also on their absolute frequency). A good rule of thumb would be to use [some type of advanced tree](http://bigocheatsheet.com/) that supports fast implementation of both operations, but sometimes the devil is in the details.

Comment: Anton, I didn't ask anybody to create a function for me.  I'm asking for some ideas.  I already gave an example implementation, but am looking for something more efficient.

Answer (score 1):

**Step 1:** sort the events by timestamp, O(n log n).

**Step 2:** For the given time, search for the interval that contains it; a binary search is O(log n).

**Step 3:** If the transition at the beginning of the interval was T->F, the answer is False; if it was F->T, the answer is True. (For times before the first event, look at the first event and guess.)

Comment: ...and repeat step(s) 1 every time an update comes in? Also, why would you ever do step 4 instead of storing the transition information along with the timestamp?

Comment: @Jon, yes on the first part, but insertion is O(log n). (If you can tell me a faster way to update the data set that doesn't make the function itself slower, I'll be much obliged.) For the second part, you're absolutely right; I'll edit...

Comment: Trees. Everything is just log n.

Comment: @Jon: please show me how to construct a tree in O(log n). I'll give you my autographed *SL2(R)*.

Comment: The point is that a tree gives you log n insert, which a sorted array (you mention binary search) does not.

Comment: @Jon: As I said, insertion is O(log n). So is a binary search (which is what some trees do, among other structures).

Comment: The data set is empty when the program starts, so I don't need step 1 per se.  I just need to do the ordered insertion as the data comes in.  I'm actually a little bit confused as to what data structure to use.  If I use an array, then I can't insert elements in the middle, but if I use a list, then I lose the ability to do a binary search for the insertion.

Comment: @NathanPeterson: It's worth taking a moment to think about which operation(s) you want to optimize. That said, a binary tree will give you O(log n) in both insertion and searching; a *balanced* binary tree will give you slightly faster searches at the cost of slight slower insertion (both still O(log n)) and more difficult code. If the events arrive *mostly* in order (or if there are other patterns), then with some effort maybe you can build something that does better than O(log n) in practice.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your data set of transitions is receiving updates progressing roughly continuously over time, the following might be a useful approach, which keeps stuff simple and yet quite efficient.

Glossary:

```
type Transition = | PositiveEdge | NegativeEdge
type DataElement = { TimeStamp : float; Channel : int; Event : Transition }
type DataSet = An opportune container type holding DataElement entries.

update: DataSet -> DataElement -> DataSet
query: DataSet -> float -> bool
```

Now some theory crafting about how update really happens in your application:

`update dataSet newElement`

1. dataSet does not contain more recent entries for newElement.Channel
2. dataSet may contain more recent entries for channel <> newElement.Channel
3. The update is rather monotonic over time (just like samples from a logic analyzer or reading port pins from a timer or periodic interrupt or receiving them from CAN bus or whatever).

If those invariants hold true,

1. Introduce the notion of "Epochs". A range of time [ts0,ts1] -> int
2. epoch: float -> int           calculate epoch from time stamp
3. range: int -> float * float   calculate time range from epoch
4. `typedef std::map<int, std::vector<DataElement> > DataSet;`

Now, `update` function calculates the epoch from the elements time stamp and does:

```
dataSet[epoch(newElement.TimeStamp)].push_back(newElement);
```

If you choose the time interval you define as 1 epoch cleverly, the number of elements per epoch will be easily and efficiently filtered for the transitions you need in your query function.

```
let query dataSet timeStamp =
   let e0,e1 = (epoch timeStamp) - 1, epoch timeStamp
   - search for transition in e1 and if not found what you need, search in e0
```

This approach allows to keep searching to a application specific "useful" range and limited. It can easily be fine-tuned by picking the right time interval which constitutes an epoch.

Also, if you feel the need to keep dataSet limited in size, you can easily remove old epochs from the map which are not relevant for function `query` anymore.